# gwt widget disappears on resizing

Tags: html, css, gwt, uibinder, gwtp

the widgets are disappearing while resizing the screen.

code :

```
<g:DockPanel width="100%" height="100%" styleName="{style.d}">
        <g:Dock direction="NORTH">
            <g:HTMLPanel width="100%" height="70px" ui:field="headerPanel"
                styleName="{style.header}" />
        </g:Dock>
        <g:Dock direction="CENTER" width="100%" height="100%">
            <g:HTMLPanel width="1000px" height="100%" ui:field="contentPanel"
                styleName="{style.container}" ></g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:Dock>
        <g:Dock direction="SOUTH" width="100%" height="30px">
            <g:HTMLPanel width="100%" height="30px" ui:field="footerPanel"
                styleName="{style.footer}" ></g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:Dock>
    </g:DockPanel>
```

each slot is filled with there own header, footer and contents respectively.

when screen is maximized

[image]

when I try to resize the window, it is not showing the right side button.

[image]

Its header, content and footer (Nested Presenters)

how to make this work.

I tried `overflow:auto;` for all the individual parts and parent window also, but no use.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: Can you give any more details?  Which widget is this; do you have a link to it?

Comment: please find the code added.

Comment: @Bennet Can you provide more info regarding where is the button and image being added? how button is moved to right side etc? because it works fine in my set up if i add the button and float it right

Comment: Have you tried to remove the width and height attributes in the <g:dock /> tags? Does this wwork?

Comment: I strongly suggest that you use 3 divs instead of the Dock widgets. You're going to have tighter control on the CSS and layout of the page.